# MySQL Data Overrides

Tags: mysql, sql, database, design-patterns, schema

I am working on a project where an **object** (a product for example) could have potentially hundreds of attributes. Objects may have *different* attributes as well. Because of this, among other more obvious reasons, it doesn't make sense to design a single table with hundreds of columns. It's just not scalable. In my mind, a *key/value* storage mechanism seems like the correct approach (specifically an [Entity-Attribute-Value Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)).

The other challenge with this data is it needs to be overridable. To describe this requirement, imagine a company wide retail products database that has "recommended" product attributes. But in different regions, they want to override several different attributes with their own custom values, and then some franchises in each region wants to add an additional override to be specific to their store. In the legacy system, there are multiple tables (each with an excessive amount of columns) where we use a combination of COALESCE (in a View) and code to find the **most specific value** based on the information we know (product, region, location, etc).

My thoughts:

```
// An object could be a product, a car, a 
// document, etc.
---------------------------------
| Table: object
---------------------------------
| - object_id
| - object_name
---------------------------------

// An attribute could be color, length, etc.
---------------------------------
| Table: attribute
---------------------------------
| - attribute_id
| - attribute_name
---------------------------------

// An owner could be a company, a region, 
// a store, etc
---------------------------------
| Table: owner
---------------------------------
| - owner_id
| - parent_owner_id
| - owner_name
---------------------------------

// Object data would be a key/value specific
// to a specific object (entity), a specific
// attribute, and specific owner (override level)
---------------------------------
| Table: objectdata
---------------------------------
| - objectdata_id
| - object_id
| - attribute_id
| - owner_id
| - value
---------------------------------
```

In thinking about this, it satisfies requirement #1 to have dynamic attributes that can be scaled easily. But for #2, while it provides the data necessary to figure out the overrides, it seems it would be a complex query and may have performance issues. For example, if I am viewing a specific **object** from the level of an **owner** 3 levels deep, I need to get all of the attributes defined at the *top level owner* where they do not have a parent, then get the attributes from each level down merging them in until I reach the specific level.

As an added bonus issue, each attribute could be a multitude of different data types (string, int, float, timestamp, etc). Do I store them all as strings and handle all validation at the application level? Hmmm.

**TL;DR;** So my issue (and question) is what is an effective data modeling pattern in which I can dynamically add and remove attributes from an object as well as have some sort of parent/child relationship for determining most specific attribute values based on a set of constraints?

**NOTE:** The retail example above is fictional, but describes the problem much better than the real situation.

Comment: I'd try another approach. One relational table for object - attribute and another table for object - owner. may be I see it too easy but I'd try this.

Comment: Magento uses a complex EAV model that somehow is related with what you need: You can create a store, or more than one, with some kind of hierachy. There is a generic configuration, and then almost all the configurable aspects of an store can be overrided at store level. How this is done at application level is hard to say, but if you want you can take a look at the database (search for store, attribure, eav, etc...) here you can get all the information about the database: http://www.magereverse.com/index/magento-database-diagram/version/1-7-0-1 I hope it helps,rather that confuse you even more